# Are all Haskell packages compatible with each other?

Tags: haskell, libraries

I see a lot of Haskell packages listed here:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:database

Are all these packages compatible with each other? If I bring in say 10 packages in order to make a program, are they all going to be OK. What if I brought in all packages listed on the page?

Imagine if you are in Java, in Java if you bring in say 10 jar's from around the web, there maybe dependancies between the JAR's that mean that one JAR requires a version other another JAR that is not a good version for a different JAR. For example, one JAR may need Hibernate version 3.0.0 and another needs Hibernate 2.0.0. So I cannot use these two jars because they don't use a common equal Hibernate version.

Comment: have you tried just importing and compiling?

Comment: That's not a good test of whether the are compatible. In Java, if I imported and compiled, even it might compile but because one JAR is dependent on a very old version of another JAR, the interface may be the same but the code behavior may be different.

Comment: @Phil The danger of a compatible interface but change in behaviour is very much less of an issue in Haskell compared to Java, because of purity. Java libraries depend on the objects you pass being in the correct state, and may update that state on the side, whereas Haskell (mostly) doesn't have objects with mutable state, and functions simply return values of their advertised type. Often this means that given a type signature, there's only one "sensible" thing it could do, and so any changes in behaviour with no interface change can only be bug fixes. In theory you are correct though.

Comment: That's a lot nicer than Java/Scala for module compatibility as in Java/Scala there is OSGi but many project's don't release in OSGi. There is Maven or SBT (Simple Build Tool) but no guarantee that any modules would work together, except by looking at the dependancies manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the same problem in Haskell, although as pointed out Cabal is exceptionally smart at resolving dependencies the best way.

Cabal will happily install multiple versions of a package, but that can lead to a subtle error when creating your own:  Your package might indirectly depend on multiple versions (Cabal warns you about that when doing `configure`), which holds a subtle surprise:  When you refer indirectly (e.g. through type inference) to a type, say State, it might be resolved to mtl 1.x at one place and mtl 2.x in another, and the two can't be unified.  This becomes a problem when you use two packages and want to combine them in your code.  It's seldomly a problem, but it is noteworthy.

Note also that Haskell packages usually depend on a version range instead of a single version.  This means that Cabal builds the intersection of accepted versions and uses the newest in it.

Comment: Fortunately the problem you describe manifests at compile-time; ghc won't build a module that tries to implicitly convert between different package-versions of data.

Answer (score 6):

No, but

1. Packages all declare dependencies including version ranges
2. If you use cabal-install it will try its hardest to keep everything consistent.  It does a pretty good job most of the time.  I have been unable to get software to build because of dependencies to old versions, but I have never seen a situation where cabal got fooled.  If cabal installs the packages for you, it is going to work; and cabal will probably install the packages for you